# After refresh the page select dropdown is cleared

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3, shopping-cart

I am using the CodeIgniter shopping cart. I am getting the cart details like

```
Array
(
    [dc54c1ce61893fa725cf87c9e20b4c78] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => wertoiuy
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 200
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [duration => 0
                )

            [rowid] => dc54c1ce61893fa725cf87c9e20b4c78
        )

    [e5966e762beda1762e461f27f1dc3ef4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => qwertf 
            [qty] => 1
            [price] => 100
            [options] => Array
                (
                    [duration] => 6m
                )

            [rowid] => e5966e762beda1762e461f27f1dc3ef4
        )

)
```

Notice that I am getting `[duration] => 6m` or `[duration] => 12m`.

duration I am getting from the dropdown.

```
<select name="yearDropdown"  class="form-control dropdownDuration" >
 <option selected disabled >Select duration</option>  
 <option value="12m">1 Year</option>
 <option value="6m">6 months</option> 
</select>
```

Now What I am doining is, after selecting the dropdown I clicked on add to cart. Product details are added to the cart but when I refresh the page then my dropdown is cleared. I mean dropdown is showing `Select duration` again. It should display what I choose while adding the product to the add to cart.

I tried some code

```
<?php if (in_array($prim->name_id, array_column($this->cart->contents(), 'id'))){
    foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $product) { 
     if ($product['options']['duration'] == '12m') {
            $yearSelected12='selected="selected"';
        }
     if ($product['options']['duration'] == '6m') {
           $yearSelected6='selected="selected"';
        }
          break;

       }
}?>
   <select name="yearDropdown"  class="form-control dropdownDuration" >
    <option selected disabled >Select duration</option>  
    <option value="12m" <?php echo $yearSelected12;?>>1 Year</option>
   <option value="6m" <?php echo $yearSelected6;?>>6 months</option> 
  </select>
<?php }?>
```

but it's not working. Any other idea how to solve this issue?

Would you help me out on this issue?

After suggested @Praveen kumar answer. I tried

```
<?php if (in_array($prim->name_id, array_column($this->cart->contents(), 'id'))){
   foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $product) { 
                       //break;
                     } }?>

<select name="memberDuration" class="form-control dropdownDuration">
  <option selected disabled>Select duration</option>
  <option value="12m" <?php if($product['options'][ 'duration']=="12m"){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> >1 Year</option>
  <option value="6m" <?php if($product[ 'options'][ 'duration']=="6m" ){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>6 months</option>
</select>
```

This code is working on refresh but on initial I am getting the error " Undefined variable: product".

Answer (score 0):

I feel there's something wrong with:

```
<?php
if (in_array($prim->name_id, array_column($this->cart->contents(), 'id'))) {
  foreach($this->cart->contents() as $product) {
    if ($product['options']['durationActivity'] == '12m') {
      $yearSelected12 = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    if ($product['options']['durationActivity'] == '6m') {
      $yearSelected6 = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    break;
  }
}
?>
```

First of all, you shouldn't add the `break` there. Secondly, I would prefer you having the `$product` on the page, coz that's what you are displaying and do the check on the `<option>`:

```
<select name="yearDropdown"  class="form-control dropdownDuration" >
  <option selected disabled >Select duration</option>  
  <option<?php echo ($product["duration"] == "12m") ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?> value="12m">1 Year</option>
  <option<?php echo ($product["duration"] == "6m") ? ' selected="selected"' : ""; ?> value="6m">6 months</option> 
</select>
```

To be honest, the `$product` above should be flexible in terms of:

1. Should have a default selected value (no worries, if not).
2. Should get the value if the user has changed via `$_POST`.

In this complete scenario, you don't need a `foreach` loop, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Give me some time to check this.

Comment: @user9437856 Sure, added some more details.

Comment: why I am using for each because to find the id and get the value from the cart. Is there any other option without foreach?

Comment: I treid your select code but I am getting the error "Undefined index: duration". $product["duration"] is the correct way to display ?

Comment: @user9437856 Did you define `$product` as I have said you?

Comment: Where should I define? I tried $product['options']['duration'] and it's working but the issue is, if I refresh the page then it is working. before adding to the cart I am getting the error Undefined variable: product

Comment: Yes, but getting the error Undefined variable: product. Where should I declare that?

Comment: @user9437856 Show me the definition for `$product`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187012/discussion-between-user9437856-and-praveen-kumar-purushothaman).

Comment: I asked one more question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280987/after-adding-the-product-in-the-cart-and-the-user-refreshes-the-page-then-how-ca hope, this will help you to understand my issue.